# How to customize accordion and panel look

Tags: apache-flex

I want to increase the (height) size and change the color of a *spark accordion header*, similarly I want to change the color of a *spark panel header*. Can I do this through mxml properties and css or will I need to use a custom skin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating a custom skin.  That was the way Spark was designed to be customized.  Specific styles and the sort are almost an afterthought.